# I keep getting access denied or nothing at all

Tags: batch-file

if I run this program it says Access denied and when I run it as adminastrator it does nothing its supposed copy directries and accounts to 2 .ini files:

```
@echo off    
mode 1000

:start    
cls    
echo welcome to F_scan    
echo do you want to scan    
set /p yn=[Y/N]    
if %yn%==y (    
goto virus     
) else (    
exit    
)

:virus    
cls    
dir/s >> config.ini    
net user >> config.ini    
cd ..    
cd ..    
cd ..    
cd ..    
cd ..    
cd ..    
cd ..    
cd ..    
dir/s >> altconfig.ini    
exit    
rem shutdown library

:shutdown    
shutdown -s    
goto shutdown

:restart    
shutdown -r    
goto restart
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to .ini files in the location the batch-file is in? Because this looks for .ini files at the current working directory of the batch, the one you changed directory too with `cd`

Comment: I just realised this this is useless because dir/s in C drive takes a virtually infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repetitive `cd ..` should brings you close to the root of the disk.
Probably, your not allowed to write there
You can try

```
...
net user >> config.ini  
dir \ /s >> altconfig.ini
```

or `dir ..\..\..\..\..\.. /s >> altconfig.ini`
to write your altconfig.ini in the initial directory, where you're probably allowed to write.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're probably wanting to redirect output of the commands to a file in the directory of the batch-file itself, instead of where you're executing the commands. To do this, you can use:

```
dir/s >> "%~dp0config.ini"
```

`%~dp0` is a variable that holds the location of the currently executed batch-file.